# MYSQL query optimization with several OR keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 8 with InnoDB tables.
There is a dynamic query that is often run (dynamic means that the condition part is assemled from the combination of AND and OR clauses).

The example would be like this:

```
SELECT a1, a2, a3, ... a10 FROM table_a
WHERE (a1 = A or a2 = A) and (a3 = B or a4 = B) .....
```

The query itself works properly, but is slow.

So far I tried to use query analyzer - the obvious issue is the OR part.

I tried to add an index to first and second column, and then the combination - but there were no improvements.

Is there any way to either index (preferably) or to rewrite query to speed the things up.

Thanks,
MTR

Comment: An open search criteria "assembled on the fly" smells like Full Text Search. MySQL comes with it and it's not difficult to use.

Comment: Hi @TheImpaler. It is not FTS. The query has several indexed columns that are not blobs/text. The challenge is the OR part. 
I am aware of potential solution with UNION, but as there are several columns, it may end up  big. So I was wondering if there is any aporach that I missed.
Thanks

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't see any general/traditional solution to this performance issue. There may be specialized ones, but that would require full table definitions, execution plans, etc. That could become a time consuming effort.

Comment: I assumed so. Anyhow, let's wait a bit, maybe someone has an idea.
Thanks @TheImpaler

Comment: Best Advice -  https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: @WilsonHauck I purchased the book some time ago, but no luck. Do you have a specific thing in mind. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) EXPLAIN SELECT sql_no_cache (rest of your query); and compl;ete TEXT results of B) SHOW CREATE TABLE table_a; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "table_a"; for analysis.  Please view profile for contact info.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck. Unfortunatelly, I cannot put the actual query/table here.
However, I am very grateful on the suggestions. I will execute them and try to see if there is anything that I may change (or ask for help again). 
Thank you very much.